# How to use event navigateToComponent

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-events

Can anyone help me? Trying to do very simple function to navigate from component to another. I copied the code from Developers guide, but for some reason it doesn't work for me.

My function to navigate to another component:

```
nav : function(component, event, helper) {
            var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
            evt.setParams({
                componentDef : "c:navToComponentTest2",
                componentAttributes: {
                    continent : component.get("v.continent")
                },
                isredirect : false
            });
            evt.fire();
    }
```

And here's the error I get in my Lightning App
[image]

EDIT: Got it working in Lightning tab. Would it be somehow possible to get it working in communities as well? Or is there anyway to make same functionality?

Comment: This event was released with the Salesforce Winter ’17 version. Are you sure that you're using this version?

Comment: By using Developer Console to create apps It wont run for navigate from component to another.make sure you running in Lightning experiance  or salesforce 1.

Comment: Thank you @vignesh it was indeed because I was trying to run it in the page of the Lightning app itself. I put it now as a Lightning tab and it seems to work. I need to get it working in communities as well, but I guess it doesn't. Any idea how I could do same functionality in community?

Comment: Yup It does'nt work in communities @G Takei

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the lightning component developer guide:

> This event is handled by the one.app container. It’s supported in
>   Lightning Experience and Salesforce1 only.

This means the event is handled only in one.app. Now, when you open a lightning tab, it opens in one.app container hence the successful run. Communities don't run on one.app hence the unavailability of the event. If you try to run it on your own lightning app, that's also not one.app, so there also it doesn't run.

One alternative I can think of for communities would be-

Have a container component which will hold initial components in it. When you want to navigate from one to another, use $A.createComponent function to create instances of your next components. Here is the developer guide for this- [Dynamically create components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm)

Comment: Yes, I found this same way. It works.